# OpenIDM - How update the UserAccountControl field in AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openidm

I am trying to update the **UserAccountControl AD field** using a specific value (66048) when I create a managed user on **OpenIDM** but I am facing an issue. The related stacktrace :

> Caused by: org.identityconnectors.framework.common.exceptions.ConnectorException: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-03
>   1A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
>   ^@]; remaining name 'CN=93ba7d80-b0d3-4af7-b199-66f1b1bd217a,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=com'
>           at org.identityconnectors.ldap.modify.LdapCreate.doCreate(LdapCreate.java:187)
>           at org.identityconnectors.ldap.modify.LdapCreate.executeImpl(LdapCreate.java:136)
>           at org.identityconnectors.ldap.modify.LdapCreate.execute(LdapCreate.java:80)
>           at org.identityconnectors.ldap.LdapConnector.create(LdapConnector.java:209)
>           at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.CreateImpl.create(CreateImpl.java:88)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor133.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.invoke(ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.java:97)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.create(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor133.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ThreadClassLoaderManagerProxy.invoke(ThreadClassLoaderManagerProxy.java:96)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.create(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor133.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.DelegatingTimeoutProxy.invoke(DelegatingTimeoutProxy.java:98)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.create(Unknown Source)
>           at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.AbstractConnectorFacade.create(AbstractConnectorFacade.java:149)
>           at org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.openicf.impl.OpenICFProvisionerService$ObjectClassResourceProvider.createInstance(OpenICFProvisionerService.java:1332)
>           ... 151 more

I am using the **default LDAP Connector** (1.4.0.0). If found on Forgerock (https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENICF-102) that the UAC Field is read only using this connector.

How can I simply update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know exactly what you're doing you can use the `userAccountControl` attribute with `OpenIDM`.

In your case, it looks like you did not provide the password (UTF 16 encoded unicodePwd)

Comment: It is working.Effectivily this was due to the lake of password during the synchronization.